# How to change dimension of a geometry mesh dynamically in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, mesh

I want to change height of my geometry meshes dynamically how is it possible
here is my [demo](http://omidgharib.ir/Map3D/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use scale to change the size of your mesh.
For example:

```
Mesh.scale.x = 2.5; // WIDTH
Mesh.scale.y = 2.5; // HEIGHT
Mesh.scale.z = 2.5; // DEPTH
```

Comment: It's not working well in my example.if is it possible i want to change the height of my meshes?